# Finding State in Street Address

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going through a dataset to clean it up and am trying to return the street addresses that contain the state abbreviation. However my current output shows the rows that also have the abbreviation somewhere in the text as well, i.e. Cat St in CA will come back due to the CA in cat even though the state is not in the street address. Is there a way to search for the state in the street addresses without this barrier?

Current Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cleanup
WHERE instr(Street, State) >= 1;
```

Current Output:

```
223 Nevada Dr Ca    Santa Cruz  CA  91616
333TestingAve       Athens      GA  30602
```

I don't want it to return the bottom one but it does due to the gA in 'TestingAve' and GA as a state, should only return the top

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (instr is not a standard SQL function.)

Comment: Some sample data would help here as well as the RDBMS you are using (mysql, mariadb, oracle, postgres, sql server, MS Access, Snowflake, Teradata, Azure, etc). They all have different functionality for parsing and searching strings. Also, parsing addresses is notoriously difficult and usually ends up with death from a thousand edge cases.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySQL Workbench, not sure about the specifics beyond that

Comment: @JNevill I have included some sample data if that helps and am using MySQL. I'm not too worried about it being 100% right since a lot of it gets manually read, but being able to pull out some before hand would be helpful

Comment: Could you just pad out your state with spaces: `instr(Street, CONCAT(' ',State,' ') >= 1`

Comment: @JNevill that did not seem to work but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE statement including a space character to force only the state chars

```
SELECT *
FROM Cleanup
WHERE Street LIKE CONCAT('% ', State, ' %')
```